# how to work with session list<t> in asp.net while refreshing page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `list<class>` for showing data in repeater control using drag and drop.

```
list.add(new class{id=0, name ="item1"});
list.add(new class{id=1, name ="item2"});
list.add(new class{id=2, name ="item3"});
list.add(new class{id=3, name ="item4"});
```

and on page load i showed  this data in Repeater...

now i want to remove one "item2" from list and show agian on repeater,

it also remain same when i am doing refresh my page

how could i do this?

Comment: how you are binding the list to the repeater, also how are you removing the item from the list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change getDate as Follow...

```
 public static List<DragAndDropData> getdata()
 {
         List<DragAndDropData> LeftSideList=new List<DragAndDropData>();
         if(Session["leftside"]!=null)
         {
           LeftSideList=(List<DragAndDropData>)Session["leftside"];
         }
         else
         {
           LeftSideList.Add(new DragAndDropData { Id = 0, Name = "Item1" });
           LeftSideList.Add(new DragAndDropData { Id = 1, Name = "Item2" });
           LeftSideList.Add(new DragAndDropData { Id = 2, Name = "Item3" });
           LeftSideList.Add(new DragAndDropData { Id = 3, Name = "Item4" });
           LeftSideList.Add(new DragAndDropData { Id = 4, Name = "Item5" });

    }
         return LeftSideList;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To your question:

> now i want to remove one "item2" from list and show agian on repeater

One possibility to select items from a list by a custom variable is to implement `IEquatable<DragAndDropData>` in your `DragAndDropData`-class.

See [MSDN IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bhkz42b3.aspx#Y456).

In the needed Method `Equals` you can compare the variable `Name` for equality.

```
public class DragAndDropData : IEquatable<DragAndDropData> {

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public Box(string n)
  {
    this.Name = n;
  }

  ...

  public bool Equals(DragAndDropData other) {
    return (this.Name == other.Name);
  }
}
```

Once you have done that, you should be able to find and remove items like this:

```
listcollection.Contains(new DragAndDropData("Item2"));
listcollection.Remove(new DragAndDropData("Item2"));
```